# Is an import partially executed when mysql import errors during that import?

Tags: import

While importing a database I received a Duplicate Entry error.

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 2825: Duplicate entry 'homerow' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Are the import instructions up until line 2825 executed or can I assume the whole import has not been executed?

Comment: Is the dump generated with `drop table if exists` and then `create table` statement ? Have you verified if the data is imported till 2825 line of the dump file , the content of dump file in linux can be read with `sed`  or similar commands

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes it is created with `drop table if exists`. I have not verified if the data is imported because I find it hard to determine what are new rows as it is a very busy database table (access logs).

Answer (score 1):

I took the time and make some tests in one of my databases. For testing purposes I used `MariaDB` version `10.5.8-MariaDB-log` , it should apply to MySQL as well.

My table has the following DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `ani_did_zoiper_test` (
  `inoltro_nr` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ani` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zoiper_path` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stato` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_record_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  UNIQUE KEY `inoltro_nr` (`inoltro_nr`,`ani`),
  KEY `inoltro_ani_st` (`inoltro_nr`,`ani`,`stato`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

I made a dump of the table which has a few rows 40-50.

```
mysqldump -u root -p asterisk ani_did_zoiper_test> /root/ani_did_zoiper_test.sql
```

Then added a duplicate value to the dump file and then restore the file.

```
dbm:~ # mysql -u root -p asterisk < /root/ani_did_zoiper.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 42: Duplicate entry '11111111111-111111111' for key 'inoltro_nr'
```

There was only one `INSERT INTO ani_did_zoiper_test VALUES` and nothing were imported in the table.

I then made a change to the dump file and added another `INSERT INTO` statement , the second insert has the duplicate values , so the dump looks like

```
LOCK TABLES `ani_did_zoiper_test` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ani_did_zoiper_test` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `ani_did_zoiper_test` VALUES (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
INSERT INTO `ani_did_zoiper_test` VALUES(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ani_did_zoiper_test` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Restore again ,

```
dbm:~ # mysql -u root -p asterisk < /root/ani_did_zoiper.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 43: Duplicate entry '11111111111-111111111' for key 'inoltro_nr'
```

The first insert block which had no duplicate was successfully imported on the table, anything after that row failed to insert.

**Note**  line 43 is the line on the dump file .

In your case anything before line 2825 is imported successfully.

To read a specific line content in unix/linux you could use ,

```
dbm:~ # sed -n '43p' /root/ani_did_zoiper.sql
INSERT INTO `ani_did_zoiper_test` VALUES('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
dbm:~ #
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to this. Very helpful to see an example on how to mimic this and verify.